Apple subscription API of app store server API returns 401 code (invalid Jason Web Token) while fetching subscriptions of a user
A user subscribed by in-app purchase subscription in my app in Apple app store. We have got the transaction Id and base64 encoded receipt data in response. We can generate the JWT in PHP by the In-app purchase key file and key Id. But when we try to fetch all subscriptions by "https://api.storekit-sandbox.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/subscriptions" by passing the "originalTransactionId", code 401 (invalid Jason Web Token) is returning. What am I doing wrong? Please help!
Our JWT creation code is below:
$keyId = 'keyid';
$issuerId = 'myissuerid';
$privateKey = file_get_contents('SubscriptionKey_keyid.p8');

// JWT Header
$header = [
    'alg' => 'ES256',  // Algorithm for signing
    'kid' => $keyId
];

// JWT Payload
$issuedAt = time();
$expirationTime = $issuedAt + (20 * 60); // JWT valid for 20 minutes
$audience = 'appstoreconnect-v1'; // Audience field

$payload = [
    'iss' => $issuerId,        // Issuer ID
    'iat' => $issuedAt,        // Issued at time
    'exp' => $expirationTime,  // Expiration time
    'aud' => $audience,
    "bid" => "com.targetleaderboard"
];

// Function to base64 encode without padding
function base64UrlEncode($data)
{
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}

// Encode Header and Payload
$base64UrlHeader = base64UrlEncode(json_encode($header));
$base64UrlPayload = base64UrlEncode(json_encode($payload));

// Create the unsigned token
$unsignedToken = $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload;

// Load the private key for signing
$privateKeyResource = openssl_pkey_get_private($privateKey);

// Sign the token using the private key and ES256 (ECDSA with P-256 curve and SHA-256)
$signature = '';
openssl_sign($unsignedToken, $signature, $privateKeyResource, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);

// Encode the signature in base64 URL format
$base64UrlSignature = base64UrlEncode($signature);

// Concatenate the JWT
$jwt = $unsignedToken . "." . $base64UrlSignature;

$jwt = $jwt . PHP_EOL;

And my subscriptions API code is below:
$endpoint = "https://api.storekit-sandbox.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/subscriptions/2000000636560504";


$curl = curl_init($endpoint);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $jwt,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
]);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

// Check for any cURL errors
if (curl_errno($curl)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($curl);
} else {
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    echo "HTTP Status Code: " . $http_code . PHP_EOL;

    // Check if the response is empty or not
    if (empty($response)) {
        echo "Response is empty, check if the originalTransactionId is valid or the API is returning correct data." . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        // Output the API response
        echo "Response: " . $response . PHP_EOL;
    }
}


Test and grab a JWT and unpack it on jwt.io. Paste the content of the JWT here to help analyse the problem (Remove the signature and any private information first!)

We tested it with jt.io and found it is okay. But please what do you mean by "Remove the signature and any private information first!". Is it the key id and key file?

Imeant you could add the JWT to your post, bet then if course either expired och without the signature so that noone could use it. I guess you just need to start printing stuff to see WHAT fails. Are you using the correct key? Is the jwt expired? Is the scope missing?

I am using the correct key Id and key file. But jwt.io saying "Invalid signature". Why it is saying so when I am using correct key Id, key file and correct issuer Id?

Because you are NOT using the correct key file. :-P If it's a public and a private key pair, you typically use the private key for signing, and public key to verify it. Can you generate a new burner key-pair and post here?

I have generated new key-pair and tested in the code. But same result occurs. I have generated key from Integrations -> Keys -> In-app purchase and created a new key and downloaded the key file and used it.

We have installed use Firebase\JWT\JWT using composer and created the JWT with the JWT signing library in PHP. But still the response code is 401 and response is empty. We have passing the correct "originalTransactionId" to the API.

Without more examples of actual JWT:s and keys, it's not really possible to provide any help. Maybe the JWT secret is base64 decoded, maybe you did expiry in milliseconds and not seconds. There are endless possibilities for bugs. :-)

It is solved using Firebase\JWT\JWT using composer and created the JWT with the JWT signing library in PHP and some tweaks in the code
